# A little confused about NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: objective-c, double, nsdecimalnumber, cgfloat

there are a short code

```
    NSString *numString = @"2128.123123";
    NSDecimalNumber *large = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:numString];
    NSDecimalNumberHandler *decimalHandler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];
    NSDecimalNumber *fin = [large decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:decimalHandler];
    NSLog(@"%@",fin);
```

seem ok, print "2128.12".

.....

but you can try numString = @"78.991";

```
NSLog(@"%@",fin)
```

print "78.98999999999999"....

why scale is invalid? expect "78.99"

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Works  for me. I think we need an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @luk2302 you're missing the point of `NSDecimalNumber`. "An object for representing and performing arithmetic on base-10 numbers."

Comment: @TurePålsson which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @Willeke I tested on Mojave, but I'm getting some linker warnings about stub files being out of sync (???) so it's possible that my system is somehow falling back to an older library...

Comment: @luk2302 The linked thread is about *binary* floating point numbers. The whole point with `NSDecimalNumber` is, that it is decimal to prevent that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fin` is ok but `NSLog` calls `doubleValue`. In earlier versions of macOS, `NSLog` did call `description` which returns "78.99". Solution:
`NSLog(@"%@", fin.description)`.

Comment: you mean, the fin value is "78.99"(although the initial value is "78.991")? NSLog makes it wrong?

Comment: and why "2128.123123" worked ok ,"78.991" not correct?╮(￣▽￣"")╭

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",fin)` does the same as `NSLog(@"%0.16g", fin.doubleValue)`. This is the broken floating point math problem. Try `NSLog(@"%0.24g", fin.doubleValue)`.